# Enter columns as parameters in DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parameter-passing

I have a Pandas DataFrame called table, and I want to see some columns of it, like:

```
table[['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C', 'col_D', 'col_E']]
```

However, I want that 'col_C', 'col_D', 'col_E' is stored in a variable called var, in order to see my results doing something like that:

```
table[['col_A', 'col_B', var]]
```

I don't know how to define my variable. I tried to set

```
var = 'col_C' + ', ' + 'col_D' + ', ' + 'col_E'
```

in order to concatenate strings, but it fails.

If it is just one column it works. I mean, doing `var2 = 'col_C'`, then I can access my table doing

```
table[['col_A', 'col_B', var2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The index is a list of strings, so use list concatenation.

```
var = ['col_C', 'col_D', 'col_E']
table2 = table[['col_A', 'col_B'] + var]
```

Comment: Or `table[['col_A', 'col_B', *var]]`